# Where should I write my code so that Composer can autoload my PHP classes?

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm new to Composer, namespaces, and autoload and I wasn't able to figure out where to write my code (under `vendor`?).

I have created a directory named `ilhan` under the `vendor`, and a file named `People.php`. Then in the main `index.php` file using `use ilhan\People.php as People;` doesn't work because I think it must have been written in `autoload_namespaces.php` initially.

But if I register `ilhan` as a vendor then I think Composer will look into the packagist.org which it isn't there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `ilhan` inside root of your project directory, not in `vendor` directory and put following in your `composer.json`,

```
   "autoload": {                    
        "psr-4": {
            "Ilhan\\": "ilhan/"
        }               
    },
```

Most probably you already have `psr-4` autoload config added in your `composer.json` file if you are using some sort of framework, in that case just add `"Ilhan\\": "ilhan/"` in to it.
Now create `People.php` inside `ilhan` directory with following content

```
<?php

  namespace Ilhan;

  class People{}
```

Make sure `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` is included in `index.php` any how, then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Now in `index.php` just bellow `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';` following should work,

```
use Ilhan\People;
```

But why do you want to use `People` class in `index.php`?

Comment: Thanks! It works exactly how I wanted! `People` class is only for testing purposes, I'll move it to another file. I use [Restler](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler).

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes into the root directory of your project (or any subdirectory). The `vendor` folder is only for packages/libraries downloaded by composer, you should never change anything in there.

To start a project just create a new file e.g. `/my-project/index.php` and require the `autoload.php` which is automatically created by composer:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

    // here comes your project code
```

For more information about autoloading see the official composer documentation at [Basic Usage: Autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

Comment: I have `require_once '../vendor/restler.php';` which loads autoload.php and then it loads Restler and Illuminate\Database. But I want to load my own classes this way.